# Use insertAfter with child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter

just a quick one. I want to change the order of two specific `div`s in the markup. Both divs have childs.

```
<div class="first">
  <elem>
    <elem> </elem>
  </elem>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <elem>
     <elem> </elem>
  <elem>
</div>
```

and want it to change to `.second` then `.first`.

I tried:

```
$('.first').insertAfter('.second');
```

which works, but without the childs. Is there any way to achieve what I want with `.insertAfter()` or is there anything else I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/d5na6guf/. Can you create a fiddle that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert after doesn't remove children elements,
check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwu0sn83/4/)

```
<div class="first">
    <div>child of first</div>
    <div>another of first</div>
</div>

<div class="second">
    <div>child of second</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says "If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved after the target (not cloned) and a new set consisting of the inserted element is returned"

In the simplest case (select by id - insert after div with a given id), my tests show that all the children come along with it.